# Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10040000 in mips. Find # of prime numbers up to 1000000

Tags: mips

I am trying to find number of prime numbers up to taken number from user. I am using "Sieve of Eratosthenes" method for this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Lets say taken number is n. I store numbers Array1 2,n. (e.g. 2,3,4,5...n). Then I will countinue to find number of prime numbers but first I want to find error(Exception occurred at PC=0x0040004c,
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10040000) to countinue. This code is working now but if n<65532. I want to find n=1000000 but gives an error and I did not find where is my fault. If anyone can help me, I appreciate...Thanks.

```html
.data 0x10000000
Input:  .asciiz "Please enter an integer number: "
Array1: 
 .word ?
 .text
 .globl main

main:
 addi $t1,$0,2
 li $v0,4
 la $a0, Input
 syscall
 li $v0,5
 syscall
 addi $t3,$v0,1
 la $s0,Array1
FirstGenerationNumbers: 
 sw $t1, 0($s0)
 addi $s0,$s0,4
 addi $t1, $t1, 1
 beq $t1, $t3, FinishGeneration
 j FirstGenerationNumbers

FinishGeneration:

 
 jr $ra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array1: 
    .word ?
```

I suppose *technically* that could be an array but it's a very small one :-)

I think you may want to allocate a little more than a single word for your array.